# Setting up VMWare Virtual Windows Server 2012 with Active directory, AD IP changing

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

On my Windows 7 Pro laptop I have have created a VMWare virtual Windows Server 2012 R2 running Active Directory and IIS. I used this [walk-through](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770347/On-Premise-Application-Identity-Windows-Authentica) to guide me.

The idea is to setup a development environment for a website that uses AD authentication.

The first issue I have is the IP address of the AD domain controller keeps changing, seems a daily thing.
using the command prompt I use: _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.Domain_Name

two days ago: 192.168.174.131
yesterday:192.168.174.134
today:192.168.174.137

As per the walk-through under the section heading '*Configure the server to communicate with the AD domain*' I configure the server to communicate with the AD domain by setting the IPv4 DNS IP, however if this keeps changing that is an issue isn't it?

[image]

Also in the walk-through, under the section heading '*Add a DNS A record for the web site*' it uses the same IP address, so it is an issue here as well.

Afraid I haven't done much networking.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening, if it should be happening and possibly a resolution please.
Have I missed something in the walk-through or has it missed something?

Comment: Hi @Hank. I can see that you're active yesterday. But you haven't commented anything on my post. Is there anything which I can help you with further? Or, is it something in my answer which is not clear to you?

Comment: Hi, yes I had quick look yesterday and again today, I may have a couple of questions, however it's the weekend here and I am spending it with family, so I will post them tomorrow. My delay is certainly not intended to be disrespectful, I will upvote as you've put alot of effort into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first issue I have is the IP address of the AD domain controller
>   keeps changing, seems a daily thing. using the command prompt I use:
>   _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.Domain_Name
>
> two days ago: 192.168.174.131 yesterday:192.168.174.134
>   today:192.168.174.137

The reason why your AD Domain Controller's IP-Address keeps changing might be because you have not configured a static IP-Address for your DC. For an AD Domain Controller, it should have a static IP-Address, or else the systems joined to this AD domain won't be able to communicate with the DC. It is recommended to have a static IP-Address for your AD DC servers.

The article has not shared the steps for setting up a DC, and I think you've mixed it up by setting up AD DS and IIS on the same server. Usually, as a recommended practice, a server having AD Domain Services role should not install additional roles like IIS. I assume you're using this just for experiment.

> As per the walk-through under the section heading 'Configure the
>   server to communicate with the AD domain' I configure the server to
>   communicate with the AD domain by setting the IPv4 DNS IP, however if
>   this keeps changing that is an issue isn't it?

I am assuming you've configured this server an AD DC in itself too, and so you need to assign a static IP for this server.

In the shared image, for the 3rd part where you've configured the DNS, you also need to assign a static IP on the top. In the current image, the default option which you've selected is "Obtain an IP Address automatically". You can assign a static IP like any of the values in the same range (e.g., 192.168.174.131, OR 192.168.174.134, OR 192.168.174.137).

In short, whatever is your AD DC's IP-Address, other systems joined to that domain should use that as a DNS value for their network configuration.

> Also in the walk-through, under the section heading 'Add a DNS A
>   record for the web site' it uses the same IP address, so it is an
>   issue here as well.

The DNS A record (Address record) is used to point a domain or a subdomain to an IP-Address of the system hosting that domain. You can think it as IP-Address resolution for the URL.

In the article pointed by you, they have done this to help other internal systems resolve your URL into the IP-Address to reach your server which is hosting the website. As AD DC has the DNS role too, you can configure A record in the AD DNS. This setting has to be done  on the AD DC server.

> Afraid I haven't done much networking.
>
> Can someone please tell me why this is happening, if it should be
>   happening and possibly a resolution please. Have I missed something in
>   the walk-through or has it missed something?

This is just an advice from my side it'd be helpful if you go through the basic networking stuff and DNS before proceeding ahead with the article content. It'd be very useful for you if you have a good networking idea which will help you to understand the AD concepts very smoothly.

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Hi @Am_I_Helpful, at last I have time to reply. Thanks for your feedback. I am setting up a development environment on my laptop to test a website, its not really an experiment, I work remotely for a company in another country and need to set up an all-in-one virtual server. I only have a laptop and although preferably you would set this up on multiple servers or virtual servers, this is not an option for me. The laptop has 8gig of RAM and 2 of that go to the virtual server.

Comment: So I have set a static IP address on the server to 192.168.174.132 as you mentioned to do above. So in my case where I have DC, AD, IIS etc installed on the same virtual machine does that mean that the configuration IP addresses for DNS and A record (as set out to be configured in the article) all need to be 192.168.174.132 also?

Comment: Will definitely do some homework on basic networking, but for the moment I need to get this running, 'time is money' as they say.

Comment: @Hank - I'd personally suggest you to setup 2 virtual servers on the same laptop. One for AD DS role, and the other for development (IIS) role, if it is possible for you. In the current setup, you actually can either set the A Record to map static IP and the URL, or, ***better*** you keep your URL as the domain name (e.g., `your.domain.name`) which would automatically get resolved on the same server.